# Can I not apply a background color to a SVG when used as background image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have a SVG being used as a background image on one element:

HTML:

```
<div id="humility" class="mix category-1" data-myorder="1"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#humility {
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;/*did not include for brevity*/);
overflow: visible;
max-height: 110px;
z-index: 10000;
```

}

Then I have a class which I would like to use to override the above:

```
.container.list .mix {
    width: 100% !important;
    height:150px !important;
    background-size: 125px 125px !important;
    background-position: 20px -8px!important;
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

However when I toggle back and forth the SVG vanishes!?

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

**UPDATE:**
Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/718BkQns/y2jmpnyh/)!

**UPDATE-2:**
There apparently is a class applied which only applies to the list view:

```
.list {
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

But when I try to fill it with `background-color: blue !important;` it spills out the container...

[image]

Comment: What browsers have you tested this in all of them or is it a specific browser? if so could you drop it in a jsfiddle.net so we could see it working / not working?

Comment: This appears to effect all mobile browsers, at least on IOS. I also tried one iPad...I added a fiddle under the UPDATE!

Comment: Both of them use the same browser i have tested in google chrome on PC and it works perfectly i would say it's a bug in iOS's browser can you get an android mobile or tablet to test it see if it works on them if so it is a iOS browser bug i have also tested in MS Edge and Firefox on PC and works perfectly in them so it would seem to be a bug in the browser on iOS like i said if you can test on android and see if it works just to double check

Comment: works for me on android/chrome

Comment: Thanks guys! I made an update. Essentially I leveraged the class the jQuery plugin is using, but now everything spills out if the container?!